# How to construct a subscription message for XMPP in NodeJS package?

Tags: node.js, xmpp, node-xmpp

I'm using [node-xmpp-client](https://github.com/node-xmpp/node-xmpp-client) package to connect to an XMPP service. The service publishes messages when it receives them from some external source. My goal:

1. Connect to the service
2. Get authenticated
3. Subscribe to some nodes that I'm interested in. (Node name is known)
4. Receive stanza from the node to know new message has come in and handle it.

I'm referencing to the [sample code](https://github.com/node-xmpp/node-xmpp/blob/master/examples/c2s.js) here.

I have managed to connect to the service with code below. Does this automatically authenticate me to the server? I don't receive any "authenticate" event. If it doesn't, how do I explicitly request for authentication?

```
var client = new xmpp.Client({
    jid: 'someuser@somedomain.com',
    password: 'somepassword',
    host:'somehost',
    port:5222
})
```

Next, how do I subscribe to a publisher node? Should I do a client.send(new xmpp.Message(..))? If yes, how the xmpp.Message should be constructed? I can see the XMPP subscription iq in XMPP's web but have difficulty in mapping it back to node-xmpp's api.

```
<iq type='set'
    from='francisco@denmark.lit/barracks'
    to='pubsub.shakespeare.lit'
    id='sub1'>
    <pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub'>
        <subscribe
            node='princely_musings'
            jid='francisco@denmark.lit'/>
    </pubsub>
</iq>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest to look at how I did this for xmpp-ftw-pubsub https://github.com/xmpp-ftw/xmpp-ftw-pubsub/blob/master/lib/pubsub.js#L111-L137

Comment: Additionally the sample you point to is a node-xmpp-server + node-xmpp-client example. You just need the client bit and an appropriate xmpp server (e.g. Prosody).